# Match month of a list of dates

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a Haskell function that takes a list of dates and a month and returns how many dates in the list match the given month. This is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to be working

```
numInMonth :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> Int -> Int
numInMonth x [] = x
numInMonth x (y:ys)

minList1 (x:xs) = currentMin x xs

currentMax :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
currentMax x [] = x
currentMax x (y:ys)
| x >= y = currentMax x ys
| otherwise = currentMax y ys

maxList1 :: [Int] -> Int
maxList1 (x:xs) = currentMax x xs
```

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: You can add formatting to your code by wrapping it between ```. It will make it easier to read. Your code is missing a lot of details, so it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Try adding more information, perhaps some example input and output might make it easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: It is not really clear to me why you wrote `minList`, `maxList1`, etc. as helper functions here.

Comment: It isn't clear what `numInMonth` is supposed to do, nor why it is relevant to the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that tuple is a date:

```
type Day = Int
type Month = Int
type Year = Int
type Date = (Year, Month, Day)
```

We can think about the logic you want with first filtering all the dates that match  the given month, and then counting them:

```
numInMonth :: [Date] -> Month -> Int
numInMonth dates month = length . filter (\(_, m, _) -> m == month) $ dates
```

Comment: What is `count`?

Comment: I switched it to `length`, which is presumably what was intended.